# Manipulating iFrame HTML with Dojo (1.6)

Tags: javascript, iframe, dojo

I have been enjoying dojo and manipulating HTML (primarily adding nodes). My problem is that I am on dojo 1.6 (for political IT reasons within my company I can't upgrade yet to something newer).

My issue is this.. (I'm really simplifying this to the basic issue)
I have a master page that has an iframe in it. The page in the iframe has several input fields in it and I am needing to clone additional input fields as needed. All of that stuff I know how to do already, if I am doing it within the same page but my experience with manipulating nodes inside an iFrame is non-existant.

Can anyone point me to an example of dojo manipulating iframe HTML from a master page? Any clues would be greatly appreciated. If I had an example as simple as how to add a div to an iFrame page from a master page, I'd be extraordinarily thrilled and that would probably get me rolling.

I'll continue my research and update this as well. I just haven't even ran across an example yet and normally my Google-Fu is good. Many thanks for any clues anyone can point me to.

Comment: Is the iframe coming from the same server (same domain, same protocol and same port)? If not then you will not be able to access the iframe content using JavaScript due to same origin policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Thanks Tom! It's definitely from the same server. I also think I"m going to have a complete answer to this posted shortly.

Comment: When messing with iframes in dojo, I usually get the document of the iframe, and then use dojo.withDoc(), to execute scripts in the context of the iframe.